# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'), Please solve this problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

this is my full code

```
const fetchTOP100Ratio = async () => {
    //     const result = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/words?"+`rowDateList=${generalFrom}&rowDateList=${genealTo}&highDateList=${generalFrom}&highDateList=${generalTo}`);
    const result = await axios.post("https://8c33c5d6-c913-4804-84f3-0bafb1081fc2.mock.pstmn.io/words?");
    const highRatios = Number(result.data.highRatio); // 60
    const naturalRatios = Number(result.data.naturalRatio); // 10
    const rowRatios = Number(result.data.rowRatio); // 30

    setTOP100Ratio({
      labels: ["매수", "중립", "매도"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "비율",
          data: [highRatios, naturalRatios, rowRatios],
          borderWidth: 1,
          backgroundColor: ["rgba(31, 6, 172, 1)", "rgba(92, 92, 92, 1)", "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)"],
          fill: false,
          borderColor: "rgba(0, 128, 128, 1)",
          tension: 0.1,
        },
      ],
    });
  };
  const [TOP100Ratio, setTOP100Ratio] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTOP100Ratio();
  }, []);
```

```
{
    "rowRatio": "30",
    "highRatio": "60",
    "naturalRatio": "10",
    "rowWord": "[]",
    "highWord": "[]",
    "rowOverlapWord": "[]",
    "highOverlapWord": "[]"
}
```

this one is json data.

and this one is my error

[image]

This error is causing the entire screen to fail to render.
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Hi 조욱희! You are very likely accessing data in your JSX before it's fetched. Check the answer to the linked thread and let us know. If it doesn't solve your problem, we will reopen it. Also, consider adding all the code and errors as plain formatted text, not images. You may also wanna read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.